# How to drag an element of ItemsControl by a certain part of it using GongDragDrop?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I've recently started working with MVVM.

I have a UserControl called TaskBox, and I created a TaskBoxVM for it. I also have a TaskListing control and a TaskListingVM for it. In the TaskListing, I have an ItemsControl to which I pass a collection of TaskBoxVMs from the TaskListingVM.

I use GongDragDrop to move items inside the ItemsControl. Everything is working correctly, but I want to move the items by clicking on the button on them, not on their entire surface.

This is my ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TaskBoxes}"
        Margin="30,0,30,0"
        dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
        dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
        dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="True"
        dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultEffectDataTemplate="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:TaskBoxVM}">
            <views:TaskBox DataContext="{Binding}"></views:TaskBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Drag drop is one of the things I personally would use code in the view for. I wouldn't use gong. I often don't use drag drop either for that matter. Once you are writing the event handlers yourself, you have control of what does what.